# NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I can’t seem to fix this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

This is my code from the file that I am loading:

```
def test_person_name
  fred = Person.new("Fred", "Jones", 43)
  result = fred.name
  assert_equals("Fred Jones", result, "Name was wrong.")
end
```

This is the other code:

```
class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
  end

  def name()
    @first_name + " " + @last_name
  end

  def age()
    @age
  end

  def ==(other)
    other.name == name
  end
end
```

Comment: Are both the code snippets in the same file?

Comment: give us the full code,or more information if you want help from us.

Comment: The code you've posted cannot produce the error you've posted.

Comment: You have more information. Ruby should be giving you a trace of how the error arose.

Comment: Methods with empty argument lists are usually defined without them for simplicity's sake. That is `def name` instead of `def name()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could get this error would be if `@first_name` is nil. And based on what you've written, that isn't possible.

In fact, if I load your class, create a `Person` the same way you've done, I get "Fred Jones" when I call `fred.name`.

Therefore, the only possible causes would be that the code you've posted to this question isn't the same you are actually running.  Or, the actual error is happening in the different place than the code you have posted.